# Disable pubnub DEBUG logs in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, pubnub

I want to disable debug logs generated by pubnub in my rails application.

Here is my pubnub initializer code :

```
if ENV['PUBNUB_ENABLED'] && (ENV['PUBNUB_ENABLED'] == 'true')
  pubnub_logger = Logger.new('/var/log/pubnub.log')

  PUBNUB = Pubnub.new(
    publish_key: ENV['PUBNUB_PUBLISH_KEY'],
    subscribe_key: ENV['PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY'],
    secret_key: ENV['PUBNUB_SECRET_KEY'],
    logger: pubnub_logger
  )
end
```

Please help me on this. Pubnub is creating a lot of debug logs which is causing disk space utilization issues in production.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before initializing pubnub, set level for your logger

```
    pubnub_logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

If you want to ignore Info logs also, then

```
    pubnub_logger.level = Logger::WARN
```